# NSubstitue for IDBCommand and error CA2100

Tags: c#, nsubstitute, idbcommand

I want substituting IDBCommand with using NSubstitue.
I must substitue field CommandText, and I did

```
string settedCommandText=string.Empty;

IDbCommand fakeCommand = Substitute.For<IDbCommand>();

command.CommandText =Arg.Do<string>(x => settedCommandText = x);
```

All right, but compiler throw  error:

> CA2100    The query string passed to 'IDbCommand.CommandText.set(string)'
>   in 'DriverTest.RevertCommandSendRevertInstruction()' could contain the
>   following variables 'Arg.Do(...)'.
>   If any of these variables could come from user input, consider using a stored procedure or a parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string concatenations.

How can I rewrite this code without suppressing this error.  I don't want use `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage`

Comment: I don't think you'll need the Arg.Do. Just assert on the `fakeCommand.CommandText` property after the test action.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems like you're creating a `fakeCommand` and then setting a variable called `command`.
Second, your `Arg.Do<string>` needs to be part of what you're passing to a method. You're not setting it as the value of the `command`.

Have a look [here (official documentation)](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/) for how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I would write

```
fakeCommand.Received(1).CommandText = Arg.Any<string>();
```

or

```
fakeCommand.Received(1).CommandText = "some specific string";
```

if I wanted to check that the string I expect is added to the command, and

```
var _ = fakeCommand.Received(1).Commandtext
```

to check that the value was actually used somewhere.  Since this is a fake command, I would think this is about as much as you'd ever want to know.